# How to align all items in cardview to center?

Tags: java, android, xml, cardview

Im having an issue with centering my buttons and text between those buttons to center. Im not sure whats wrong, because that "Some example" text placed nicely. Is there some other "command" to use with buttons? I already tested layout_gravity:center, but that doesnt work some reason.. Anyone can help me?

[Issue pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpPYw.png)

Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cardCornerRadius="80dp"
        android:cardElevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Some example"
                android:textSize="40dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kpl1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="10"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addCount"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="30dp">

            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/kpl1">

            </Button>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

My code should work for you as long as you have no problem with the extra `LinearLayout`. I couldn't find a better way, as there seems to be no way to center multiple objects in a `RelativeLayout` without grouping them in a `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cardCornerRadius="80dp"
        android:cardElevation="10dp">


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Some example"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="30dp">

            </Button>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kpl1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="10"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="30dp">

            </Button>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cardCornerRadius="80dp"
    android:cardElevation="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Some example"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">
            
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="30dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kpl1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="10"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="30dp">

            </Button>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

while using cardview, surround all your views in a parent linearLayout
such that you can control the view.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).